# CSS texts from different divs to flow

Tags: css

Let's say I have the following divs: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/m800pthq/1/)

```
<div>
  <div class="first">Hello My name is </div>
  <div class="second">Something else</div>
</div>
```

Under a max-width, the `first` part and `second` part breaks away to next line. Is there a way to keep the words next to each other?

Comment: Is there a need to use `display: flex`? Because as far as i see, changing flex to block or inline block fixes it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m800pthq/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See the Solution Below**

just add `display:table;` to `.genral` and `display:table-cell;` and `white-space:nowrap;` to `.first, .second`

```css
.general {
    background: #ebeff1;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    max-width: 205px;
    display: table; /*Changed*/
}
.first {
    margin-right: 7px;
}

/*New Added*/
.first, .second{
   display: table-cell;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
   
p.pp {
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<p class="pp">
   When overflow, the words go to next line: Not good.
</p>
    <div class="first_sample general">
      <div class="first">Hello My name is </div>
      <div class="second">something else</div>
    </div>
    
<p class="pp">
   If there is a space, then words simply flow to next each other: Good.
</p>
    <div class="second_sample general">
      <div class="first">Hello My name is </div>
      <div class="second">something</div>
    </div>
    
<p class="pp">
    The look I am trying to achieve:
</p>
    <div class="third_sample general">
      <div class="first">Hello My name is something else </div>      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `display: inline` or `inline-block` in your `first` and `second` divs.

```css
.general {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.first,
.second {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="first_sample general">
  <div class="first">Hello My name is </div>
  <div class="second">something else</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `white-space:nowrap;` property.

```css
.general {
    background: #ebeff1;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    max-width: 205px;
    display: flex;
}
.first {
    margin-right: 7px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.second {
    white-space:nowrap;
}

p.pp {
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<p class="pp">
   When overflow, the words go to next line: Not good.
</p>
    <div class="first_sample general">
      <div class="first">Hello My name is </div>
      <div class="second">something else</div>
    </div>
    
<p class="pp">
   If there is a space, then words simply flow to next each other: Good.
</p>
    <div class="second_sample general">
      <div class="first">Hello My name is </div>
      <div class="second">something</div>
    </div>
    
<p class="pp">
    The look I am trying to achieve:
</p>
    <div class="third_sample general">
      <div class="first">Hello My name is something else </div>      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.general {
    background: #ebeff1;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    max-width: 405px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```